# Research on stackexchange

Tags: graduate-school

I have some nice research in math and philosophy but I don't know if I should share some of it in question form here. Can I still get it published in a journal if I post on philosophy and math stackexchanges?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that either of those SE sites would welcome those sorts of contributions. Are you familiar with the concept of "preprints"?

Comment: @BryanKrause I know it has to do with arxiv. I don't even know Latex though.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/73498/63475 https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16832/why-upload-to-academic-preprint-sites-like-arxiv https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75733/when-to-upload-preprint-or-abstract-to-online-repository https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13089/what-are-the-boundaries-between-draft-manuscript-preprint-paper-and-article are some other questions that you might find relevant.

Comment: This is also on topic on meta!

Comment: Asking Math.SE or Philosophy.SE if this sort of content would be acceptable on those sites would be on topic on Meta, but the question "can I publish after posting something on StackExchange" would not be on topic on a meta site.

Comment: Previously asked on Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370104/177408

Comment: @anon you don't need to know LaTeX to post to arXiv. It certainly helps your work to be taken seriously, though, especially in maths and physics. It's very easy to learn -- there is even a whole Stack Exchange dedicated to it (TeX.SE)!

Comment: @anon You have asked more or less this question a while ago: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17479/when-should-ideas-be-shared-on-stackexchange, Why again?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can usually submit research you have previously published online to a journal. That's effectively a preprint. These are almost universal in maths, physics and computer science (as I understand it) and increasingly common in other disciplines (such as in medical science where preprints have been high profile during the pandemic, for better or worse). A few journals may still object to this practice but that objection is becoming less common as preprints gain in popularity.

No, in this specific case you probably shouldn't share it to the Math and Philosophy stack exchanges as those sites exist to answer questions, not discuss topics of interest to the poster.

Comment: Some journals do not accept submissions that have been publicly made available as preprints.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche - fair point, I'll make an edit to the post.

Comment: It is possible to ask a (research) question that is on topic on an SE site and answer it yourself. Is there a convention that this should not be done? It certainly does not happen frequently (if at all), presumably because there are more suitable ways of publishing.